# How can I turn this string into a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, string, json

I have the following string coming in from users and need to turn it into JSON.

```
2r,5g|3b,2r,4y|3g
```

I would like to convert it to JSON with JavaScript. Here is what I would like the JSON to look like:

```
rounds = { 
    "round" : {
        "interval" : {
            "time" : "2",
            "color" : "r"
        },
        "interval" : {
            "time" : "5",
            "color" : "g"
        }
    },
    "round" : {
        "interval" : {
            "time" : "3",
            "color" : "b"
        },
        "interval" : {
            "time" : "2",
            "color" : "r"
        },
        "interval" : {
            "time" : "4",
            "color" : "y"
        }
    },
    "round" : {
        "interval" : {
            "time" : "3",
            "color" : "g"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not really sure where to start here so any help is appreciated!

Comment: You want to do this in JavaScript or in a server-side language like PHP?

Comment: represented JSON seems invalid to me

Comment: I'm sorry, I want to do this in JavaScript...  I will update the question.

Comment: The JSON _is_ invalid.  You can't have multiple fields called "round".

Comment: You should at least consider changing multiple rounds to `'rounds': [{"intervals": []}, {"intervals": []}]`

Comment: I'm sorry, looks like I misunderstood how JSON is formatted. Thanks for the correction. I guess I will end up putting an integer at the end of my rounds and intervals as Igor suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
var strRounds = "2r,5g|3b,2r,4y|3g";
var roundsSplit = strRounds.split("|");

var rounds = {};

for (var i = 0; i < roundsSplit.length; i++){
    var intervalsSplit = roundsSplit[i].split(",");

    if (intervalsSplit.length > 0){
        rounds["round" + i] = {};
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < intervalsSplit.length; j++){
        rounds["round" + i]["interval" + j] = {
            "time": intervalsSplit[j][0],
            "color": intervalsSplit[j][1]
        };
    }
}
```

But I have to say, that JSON written by you is not valid because its' fields must have unique names. I've used names like `round0`, `round1`... and `interval0` and so on.

Comment: The proper way is to make an array of rounds, but +1 nevertheless.  Might be nice to rewrite for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

The format you give is not valid JSON, since you have multiple instances of the same key. The following is an attempt at something more sane, by using arrays instead of objects with multiple instances of the same key:

```
function userStringToJSON(userString) {
    var arrayOfRounds = userString.split("|").map(function (roundString) {
        return roundString.split(",").map(function (intervalString) {
            var time = parseInt(intervalString, 10) + "";
            var color = intervalString.substring(time.length);

            return { time: time, color: color };
        });
    });

    return JSON.stringify(arrayOfRounds);
}
```

Then `userStringToJSON("2r,5g|3b,2r,4y|3g")` gives the string:

```
[[{"time":"2","color":"r"},{"time":"5","color":"g"}],[{"time":"3","color":"b"},{"time":"2","color":"r"},{"time":"4","color":"y"}],[{"time":"3","color":"g"}]]
```

which is equivalent to the JavaScript array of array of objects given by

```
[
    [
        { time: "2", color: "r" },
        { time: "5", color: "g" }
    ],
    [
        { time: "3", color: "b" },
        { time: "2", color: "r" },
        { time: "4", color: "y" }
    ],
    [
        { time: "3", color: "g" }
    ]
]
```

In older browsers you will need [es5-shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) for `map`, and [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) for `JSON.stringify`.

Answer (score 0):

Split the string on "|"  to get a new round, and then split each substring on "," to get intervals for that round.

So you easily create a javascript map, and then use a [Map to JSON](http://www.json.org/js.html) conversion to get the JSON needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much this will help you, but it does exactly what you need:

```
<script>
    var string = "2r,5g|3b,2r,4y|3g";
    var inSplit = string.split('|');

    var myJson = "rounds = { ";

    for (var one = 0; one < inSplit.length; one++){
        var inOne = inSplit[one].split(',');
        myJson = myJson + '\n    "round" : {';
        for (var rnd = 0; rnd < inOne.length; rnd++){
            val = inOne[rnd].split('');
            myJson = myJson + '\n        "interval" : {';
            myJson = myJson + '\n            "time" : "'+val[0]+'",';
            myJson = myJson + '\n            "color" : "'+val[1]+'"';
            myJson = myJson + '\n        }';
            if(inOne.length > (rnd+1)){
                myJson = myJson + ',';
            }
        }
        myJson = myJson + '\n    }';
        if(inSplit.length > (one+1)){
            myJson = myJson + ',';
        }
    }
    myJson = myJson + '\n}';
    document.write(myJson);
</script>
```

Look on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rstDK/)